# Is this my doorbell transformer?

Tags: transformer, doorbell

Is this the transformer for my doorbell? It is located in the furnace room, but it looks like it is connected to the furnace. I am just wondering because I have been searching for the transformer and a lot of posts say it should be near the furnace area. Thanks for any help.

SORRY FOR THE SIDEWAYS PHOTOS, BUT I CANT ROTATE

[image]
[image]

Comment: simple test .... disconnect one wire .... does the doorbell stop working?

Comment: looks kind of big for a doorbell transformer.

Comment: @jsotola OP doesn't say **why** they are looking for the transformer. If it is "doorbell isn't working and I tested the switch and I'm not getting any power" then "disconnect one wire" won't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

Anything is *possible*, but my bet is on a **thermostat** transformer. Typical (US) thermostats run on 24V AC. Typical doorbells (though there seems to be less consistency than with thermostats) use 16V AC.

Get a multimeter. Test the voltage:

- 24V - Thermostat
- 16V - Doorbell

Something else? Post it here and we can try and figure it out.